# Array input to one class variable c++

Tags: c++

I need to create a class of Students where I need to store their name, surname and subjects that they have in uni. How do I need to assign different subjects to different students? User should input it from console. What my class and input should look like? Heres is the code I have so far For example: there are two students Mark Jacobs and John Johny. Mark has 3 subjects: Math, Physics, Geography and John only has 2 Math and Economy.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Student{
private:
string name; 
string surname;
int courseNo;
string subjects[100]; 

public:
Student(string name = "empty", string surname = "empty")
{
    this->name = name + surname;
}

~Student(){


}

void setFullName(string name, string surname){
    this->name = name;
    this->surname = surname;
}

string getFullName(){
    return name + " " + surname;
}

void setSubject(string subjects[100]){
    this->subjects[90] = subjects[90];

}

string getSubject(){

    return subjects[90];
}

string toString() const
{
    return "Studentas: " + this->name;
}


};
int main() {

int number_of_students; 
int number_of_subjects = 0; 
int choice;
string subjects[90]; 
string name;
string surname;

cout << "Enter number of students: ";
cin >> number_of_students;

Student Studentas[number_of_students];

cout << "Enter " << number_of_students << " students names and surnames: " << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < number_of_students; i++) {
    cin >> name >> surname;
    Studentas[i].setFullName(name, surname);
}

for (int i = 0; i < number_of_students; i++) {
    cout << i+1 << " Student: " << Studentas[i].getFullName() << endl;
}

cout << "Choose which students subjects you want to enter: ";
cin >> choice;

if(choice == 1){
    cout << "Enter " << Studentas[choice-1].getFullName() << " number of subjects: ";
    cin >> number_of_subjects;

    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_subjects; i++) {
        cin >> subjects[i];
        Studentas[choice-1].setSubject(subjects);
    }

cout << "Studying subjects are: " << endl;
for(int i = 0; i < number_of_subjects; i++){

    cout << Studentas[choice-1].getSubject() << endl;
}
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `this->subjects[90] = subjects[90];` copies only a *single* string from `subjects` to `this->subjects`. And perhaps you need to use a kind of *dynamic array* (a.k.a. `std::vector`) to store the subjects?

Comment: Could you write an example how should I do it in class method and access it in main function?

Answer (score 0):

I have taken your code changed a little bit, I hope this is what you are looking for

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Student {
private:
    string name_;
    string surname_;
    int courseNo_;
    std::vector<string> subject_list_;

public:
    Student(string name = "empty", string surname = "empty")
    {
        name_ = name + surname;
    }

    void setFullName(string name, string surname) {
        name_ = name;
        surname_ = surname;
    }

    string getFullName() {
        return name_ + " " + surname_;
    }

    void setSubject(string subject) {
        subject_list_.push_back(subject);
    }

    const std::vector<string>& getSubjects() {
        return subject_list_;
    }

    string toString() const
    {
        return "Student as: " + name_;
    }
};


int main() {
    std::vector<Student> student_list;
    int number_of_students;
    int number_of_subjects = 0;
    int choice;
    string subject;
    string name;
    string surname;

    cout << "Enter number of students: ";
    cin >> number_of_students;

    cout << "Enter " << number_of_students << " students names and surnames: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_students; i++) {
        cin >> name >> surname;
        student_list.push_back(Student(name, surname));
    }

    int i = 1;
    for (auto student : student_list) {
        cout << i++ << " Student: " << student.getFullName() << endl;
    }

    cout << "Choose which students subjects you want to enter: ";
    cin >> choice;

    if (choice <= number_of_students) {
        choice -= 1;
        cout << "Enter " << student_list[choice].getFullName() << " number of subjects: ";
        cin >> number_of_subjects;

        for (int i = 0; i < number_of_subjects; i++) {
            cin >> subject;
            student_list[choice].setSubject(subject);
        }

        cout << "Studying subjects are: " << endl;
        const auto& subject_list = student_list[choice].getSubjects();
        for (auto& subject : subject_list){
            cout << subject << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what I needed. And then another question. How do I now should assign grades to each of the subject output their average for student and output all average of group?

Comment: I'll suggest writing another class "Subject"  that will do all the extra things and keep this "Subject" array in "Student " class instead of "std::vector<string> subject_list_;"  ... happy coding :)